# C# using SQL dependency to receive notification when query returns no rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am currently working on an asp.net web application and have been interested in implementing a SQL dependency into a part of it. There is a process where users will update some rows in a SQL server database table. A windows service hosted elsewhere will receive a sqldependency query notification, and process the data. What I want is for the web application to post back once it detects that the data processing has completed. The way I'm trying to do this at the moment is to create a SQLdependency with a query that monitors the relevant rows. The only notification I care about is when the query no longer returns rows (meaning the data has finished processing). Is there any clean way to make this work? My current implementation receives notifications for every change made, which come as the data is processed.

Comment: Not really. Why not update a field somewhere to say you're done instead? Also, don't rely too much on SqlDependency - it doesn't give you any guarantees.

Comment: Well there are multiple services that are responsible for processing different parts so having a field that's updated on finish would be difficult considering just because one service finished processing doesn't give a guarantee that all requested data has been processed. Only the web application knows which updates were requested so only it can determine when all are finished.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use a field on a table to track the changes. But you make the field an int (this will be similar to how `@@Trancount works`). The premise is this:

1. Each service that begins updates will increase that field by one.
2. As they finish, they decrease that field by one (and your web app can be the one controlling that aspect)
3. (NB) On error the services need to be aware to decrease the field by one.

Your SqlDependency will have a query which monitors this table, selecting that field when it changes. When it is zero, it means that no more rows are returned.